# use of undeclared identifier 'git_diff_perfdata' with libgit2

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to write some code that uses `git_diff_perfdata` from the `Libgit2` library.

```
git_diff_perfdata s;
```

However, when compiling on my Mac I get the error:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'git_diff_perfdata'
```

My understanding is that `Libgit2` is meant to be used exclusively through the inclusion of `git2.h`. Is that correct?

`git_diff_perfdata` is defined in `sys/diff.h` and used in `status.h`

Should I be including `sys/diff.h` directly. If so, why? Alternatively, what errors might I be making? Looking at the header code I'm unable to see how `sys/diff.h` is included through anything that is included by `git2.h`.

Additionally, from what I can tell `git_diff_perfdata` isn't meant to be an opaque data type (i.e. only the pointer is defined).

I'm using the code downloaded from:
https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/archive/v0.26.0.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers in `sys` are part of the public API, but they're a bit lower level. You can think of them as internal implementation details that have been made public because they might be useful to application developers. If you want to use them, include them directly.